# How to display only an organization name only?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to console log an organisation name but get undefined abut when I console log the object I'm able to get the org name and the id. For example;

When I run this, I get the result display in the console log:

```
const existingOrganisationID = await Organisation.findOne({ _id: { "$eq": organisationid } })
console.log(existingOrganisationID)

{
  _id: new ObjectId("61fd46ad360f1a287ac6cc65"),
  organisationName: 'OneExample Pte Ltd',
   __v: 0
}
```

But when I run this, I get undefined.

```
console.log(existingOrganisationID.organisationName)

undefined
```

Here is the full code for a get API:

```
router.get('/api/organisation/:id', async (req, res) => {
      let organisationid = req.params.id
      const existingOrganisationID = await Organisation.findOne({ _id: { "$eq": organisationid } })
      console.log(existingOrganisationID)
      console.log(existingOrganisationID.organisationName)    
})
```

Where did I go wrong? thanks

Comment: Can you add the full code, it seems correct. The key name and await everything seems correct. Can you add more code where are you calling these lines?

Comment: hi Apoorva Chikara, I have updated the post with the full code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the query. Try this:

```
router.get('/api/organisation/:id', async (req, res) => {
      let organisationid = req.params.id
      const existingOrganisationID = await Organisation.findOne({ _id: { "$eq": organisationid } }).exec();
      console.log(existingOrganisationID)
      console.log(existingOrganisationID.organisationName)    
})
```

You can check [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) for more details.